# Group by and combine intersecting/overlapping geometries in geopandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, gis, geopandas, shapely

I have a geopandas dataframe that has several rows with overlapping polygon geometries along with an index (unique and sequential). I want to merge the overlapping polygon geometries into a multi-polygon and keep the corresponding minimum index of the individual overlapping polygons.

For example:
The geodataframe is as follows:

[original geodataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFf6I.png)

Lets say the polygon geometries with index 10233, 10235, 10238 overlap. I want a single row for this with these geometries merged in a multi-polygon (instead of 3 separate geometries) and the corresponding index should be the minimum index of the 3 rows that is 10233. I would like to do this for the entire geodataframe

I tried using the dissolve function from geopandas:

`gdf = gdf.dissolve(by = 'index').reset_index()`

This does not do anything since 'index' is unique. I also tried:

`gdf = gdf.dissolve().reset_index()`

However, this combines all geometries into single row of multi-polygons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you had in mind:

[image: Input geometries]

```
import geopandas as gpd

# load your geodataframe ..

# self join on geodataframe to get all polygon intersections
intersects = gdf.sjoin(gdf, how="left", predicate="intersects")

# dissolve intersections on right index indices using the minimum value
intersects_diss = intersects.dissolve("id_right",aggfunc="min")

# dissolve again on left index using minimum
intersects_diss = intersects_diss.reset_index().dissolve("id_left",aggfunc="min")
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

Anyone coming across this is wondering how to solve this issue if we have “polygon-chains”, e.g.:

- Polygon A intersects with B
- Polygon B intersects with A and C
- Polygon C intersects with B

This is how you could solve it (inspired by the answer of @NielsFlohr):

```py
import geopandas as gpd

# load your geodataframe ..

# self join on geodataframe to get all polygon intersections
intersects = gdf.sjoin(gdf[["geometry"]], how="left", predicate="intersects").reset_index()

# dissolve intersections on right index indices aggregating to list
intersects_diss = intersects.dissolve(
    "index_right",
    aggfunc=lambda x: x.tolist(),
)
intersects_diss["id"] = gdf["id"]
intersects_diss.geometry = intersects_diss.geometry.buffer(0)

# determine which polygons are connected
intersects_diss["polygon_group"] = None
for i in range(len(polygons)):
    if intersects_diss.loc[i, "polygon_group"] is None:
        intersects_diss.loc[i, "polygon_group"] = i
    poly_group = intersects_diss.loc[i, "polygon_group"]
    intersects_diss.loc[intersects_diss["index"].apply(lambda x: i in x), "polygon_group"] = poly_group

# dissolve on the polygon_group
intersects_diss = intersects_diss.dissolve(
    "polygon_group",
    aggfunc="min",
)
intersects_diss.geometry = intersects_diss.geometry.buffer(0)
```

Most probably not the best way but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful, so thanks!

On my data, it exhibited the problem that it would not correctly assign IDs as expected. It depended on the order in which the polygons were presented. To avoid this problem, use the first_valid_index of the 'indices' rather than the 'group_id' directly...

```py
for i range(len(temp)):
    first_valid_index = temp.loc[temp['indices'].apply(lambda x: i in x), 'group_id'].first_valid_index()
    temp.loc[i, 'group_id'] = i if first_valid_index == None else temp.loc[first_valid_index, 'group_id']
    id = temp.loc[i, 'group_id']
    temp.loc[temp['indices'].apply(lambda x: i in x), 'group_id'] = id
```

A further improvement was to use nditer under the hood, leading to a 30 times reduction in execution time (not yet linear however):

```py
start = time.time()
counter = it.count()

indices = temp['indices'].to_numpy()
groups = pd.Series([None] * len(temp))

for i, array in tqdm(zip(counter, indices), total=len(temp)):
    first_valid_index = groups.loc[array].first_valid_index()
    id = i if first_valid_index == None else groups.loc[first_valid_index]
    groups.loc[array] = id
end = time.time()
print(f'Loop over {len(temp)} took {end-start}s')

temp[group_id] = groups.copy()
```